# Getting the values of the maximum record

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am facing some difficulties while developing a report. The problem is that I am getting a number of values in the Details section and I want only to display the record which is having the maximum event number for each group (one record to be shown for each group).

My report structure is:

- GH1:{Deal_NO} 1 -- Suppressed
- Details:

  ```
  {Deal_NO} {Amount} {Event_no} {Comments} 

  1         1000     222        Rate 
  1         2345     655        Principal 
  1         444      111        Sell
  ```
- GF1: {Deal_NO} -- Suppressed

So, my result should be:

```
1         2345     655        Principal
```

So, please instruct me on how to do that.
I tried to define in the Group Selection under Select Expert:
`{Event.Event_no}=maximum({Event.Event_no},{Deal_No})`, but some deals have disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use that logic with record or group selection. Instead, use the logic you have but use it to suppress the Details Section. So,

```
//Suppress Details if the current record is not the record with the
// maximum amount for the group
{Event.Event_no}<>maximum({Event.Event_no},{Deal_NO})
```

Now, when you run the report every record will be suppressed *except* for the one with the maximum amount per group.

Comment: Thanks I will try the solution